# How to alias "git push" into itself + running a script?

Tags: bash, git, alias

I need to run a script which notifies my CI server after I push. Therefore I need to alias "git push" into "git push; powershell script.ps1". Here is what I am trying:

```
$ alias git push='git push; powershell script.ps1'
bash: alias: git: not found
```

Alternatively, denoting whitespace characters returns this:

```
$ alias git\ push='git push; powershell script.ps1'
bash: alias: `git push': invalid alias name
$ alias "git push"='git push; powershell script.ps1'
bash: alias: `git push': invalid alias name
```

How can I alias my script to run every time I push?

This worked:

```
git config --global alias.push "push; powershell ./script.ps1"
```

The command runs, but using "git push" still doesn't run my script.

Yes, I know that I can use webhooks for this, but it is imperative that the CI server remains fully local. Yes, I know that I can use NGROK for that, but my company does not allow it.

Comment: Aliases don't allow spaces, you have use instead `-` or `_`.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca While that allowed for the alias command to work, my script still doesn't run after use "git push"

Comment: @RomainValeri Works! Feel free to make it an answer so I can choose it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't allow alias names to override proper command names. Use another label for your alias.

And if the alias content mixes a git command and shell commands, you'll have to prepend a `!` to tell git to pass the command for the shell to interpret.

Try

```
git config --global alias.p '!git push; powershell ./script.ps1'

# then to invoke it, just
git p
```

Another slight improvement would be to use `&&` instead of `;` to chain your commands, in case the push fails. It would then stop from executing the unnecessary following.

```
git config --global alias.p '!git push && powershell ./script.ps1'
```